# Angularjs Signalr load dynamically generated in web api

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I want to integrate SignalR with an AngularJs app.

```
$scope.ceva = function () {
    var proxy = $.connection.chatHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log("started");
    })
}
```

I included the next file:     `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.0.js"></script>`

But I get the following error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. script src='/signalr/js'>

What files do I need to load?

Edit:

**So I understood that I need to load the dynamically generated Hub. How could I do that in WebApi??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the SignalR dynamic script (should be placed underneath the jquery.signalr script reference):

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: From where to get that? I am using WebApi as server,

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted web api server? Or are you using an ASP.NET WebAPI project that runs on IIS?

Comment: Found the second problem. Needed to add "app.MapHubs();" to Owin.
Thanks!

Comment: @Shay Friedman,http://localhost:46421/signalr/hubs I check this.It show some javascript file.But when I use it var proxy = $.connection.myHub;
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log("started");
            }) in my external controller.It show that the message Cannot read property 'myHub' of undefined